# Android - Error inflating class EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Good afternoon, I'm trying to solve a problem but I can not. I have two smartphones, a Nexus 5(Android 6.0) and one ZenFone 2(Android 5.0). The error only persisted only in ZenFone.

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/TextLabel">
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/et_login_pass"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/LoginPlaceholderPassword"
     android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error
>   inflating class EditText
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)

What do I do?

Comment: Please can you post your xml layout and any styles you are using.

Comment: @vguzzi Ready. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your `layout_width` to `match_parent` and check if your definitely compiling the two dependencies you need in your build.gradle file please.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Comment: If above doesn't work can you also paste your `TextLabel` style.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here with ZenFone 2(Android 5.0).

Update your Android Support to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

Remove:

```
android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
```

PS: Please replace **fill_parent** to **match_parent** =)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a sub class that extends EditText.
For Example:

```
public class Text extends EditText {
    public Text(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Then use this class in xml file instaed of EditText

```
<com.example.edittextproblem.Text
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="haha"/>
```

and your problem will be solved :)